# If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, prove that $|(A^TB)|^2\leq|A^TA||B^TB|$; when is this an equality?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be square $n$-matrices. Prove that $|(A^TB)|^2\leq|A^TA||B^TB|$. Also, under what circumstances are the left and the right side equal?

I've tried multiple times, both sides should definitely be positive and since $|A^TA|=|AA|$ and $|AA|=|A||A|$ and so on, I would only get that $|A||A||B||B|=|A||A||B||B|$, which is obviously wrong. The only problem I see is that I don't understand why $(A^TB)$ is in parentheses and $A^TA$ and $B^TB$ aren't.

Comment: This looks like the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to me.

Comment: What norm $|\cdot|$ are you using on these matrices?

Comment: Determinants. Also, I shall look into the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Determinants? If you are using the operator norm coming with the Euclidean norm, it is true by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @AlexOlssen Indeed, since $\det (A^TB)$ defines an inner product in the space of square matrix. It seems that the OP forgot the $\det$ or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If $|X|$ means the determinant of a matrix $X$ (as noted in your comment), then as you said, $|A^TB|^2=\left(|A||B|\right)^2=|A|^2|B|^2=|A^TA||B^TB|$. So, equality always holds. It's just a matter of taste to put $A^TB$ inside a pair of parantheses; I'm surprised that this could be a source of confusion.

Note, however, that as the others suggest, the original problem is perhaps to show that $\|A^TB\|^2\le\|A^TA\|\|B^TB\|$ for some *matrix norm* $\|\cdot\|$. Make sure that you haven't misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that if you're using the Frobenius norm then $|AB|_F\leq|A|_F|B|_F$.